# Outlier Detection for non linear data for regression

Tags: machine-learning, outlier

I'm grappling with two parameters exhibiting an 82% correlation, showcasing a non-linear relationship and continuous fluctuations. Despite attempting LocalOutlierFactor in scikit-learn, outlier removal remains challenging. Parameter 1 ranges from 0.01 to 0.077, while Parameter 2 spans 3 to 12. Seeking advice on effective outlier removal methods to improve the correlation and better prepare the data for training a random forest regression model. Any insights or experiences would be greatly appreciated.